# Basis for subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider $V= \left \{ u= \begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2\\ 
x_3
\end{bmatrix} : x_1-x_2+2x_3=0\right \}\subset K^3$.

What is the basis of $V \subset K^3$

The format of the subspace is proving itself difficult to me. I know the span of the vectors in the basis is equal to the subset and that the vectors in the basis are linearly independent. I furthermore know the dimension is equal to the ammount og vectors in the basis of the subspace. Normally I would reduce to reduced echeleon form and be done. What approach would work here? I cant seem to make a matrix for the subspace.

Comment: $\{(1,1,0), (0,1,1)\}$.

Comment: Why? How? I need to show an approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
\left \{ \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{bmatrix} : x_1-x_2+2x_3=0\right \}
&=
\left \{ \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{bmatrix} : x_1=x_2-2x_3\right \}
\\&=
\left \{ \begin{bmatrix} x_2 - 2 x_3 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{bmatrix} : x_2, x_3 \in K\right \}
\\&=
\left \{ x_2 \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + x_3 \begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} : x_2, x_3 \in K\right \}
\\&= \operatorname{span} \left \{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \right \}
\end{align*}
and the two vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for!

Comment: @bymathformath Note that this is the solution space of the linear system with reduced row echelon form $(1\ \ {-1} \ \ 2\ |\ 0)$, and you can apply your favorite method of getting a basis of a kernel from reduced row echelon forms. For example solve for the pivot variables and leave the others as parameters, that's what I did here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, $V$ is given by the kernel of the linear mapping $f:K^3\rightarrow K: (x_1,x_2,x_3)^T\mapsto x_1-x_2+x_3$.

The dimension formula $\dim K^3 = \dim ker(f) + \dim image(f)$ applies and shows that
$\dim V = \dim ker(f)=2$.
Now choose two linearly independent vectors of $V$ as shown by the comment above: $(1,1,0)^T$ and $(0,1,1)^T$. By the dimension of $V$, they form a basis of $V$.

Comment: My apologies there was a mistake. It is $2x_3$ as seen in the post now.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B = \{(1,1,0) , ( 0, 2,1) \}$ and we claim that this is a basis.

Observe that since $x +2z = y$ we have $(x,y,z) = x(1,1,0) + z(0,2,1)$ for any $x,y,z$ in $K$. So $B$ spans $V$. I leave it to you to verify that $B$ is linearly independent.